# workflow on Close-lost opportunity Stage

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to have a workflow that only works when the opportunity stage is on Close-lost and then send and email every month for 3 month to the lead ? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can define the rule criteria as when stage = Closed Lost. and add 3 time dependent email alerts under 3 separate time trigger. 1 after 30 days, 2nd after 60 days and 3rd after 90 days.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: but it has only 30 days, how do you make the second 30 days and third 30 days?

Comment: and how do you send that to lead a automatically? so If I am the lead and this is my email address how do you select that lead, not the opportunist creator

Comment: for second, you can set time trigger for 60 days and for 3rd set it as 90 days.

Comment: And you must be having any email field on opportunity as lead email(if not then you can create one and populate on lead conversion from lead to opportunity), so use this field as email recipient.

Comment: I am trying to see where you select the lead email , I am in email update field and here is what I see, I just updated the question

Comment: i just mentioned in my previous comment that you will need the email value in particular field of type email on your opportunity. so you need to create a field of type email on opportunity and populate the lead email into this field. after creation, this email field will be available on new email alert page.

Comment: I do have a field called Email in Lead, how do you carry that into opportunity?

Comment: You can update email on opportunity from lead while lead conversion in your apex code.